# D3 Bars outside of chart after un-zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart using D3. The x-axis is dates. Also has a focus zoom. I started the chart base on [Zoomable Stacked Bar Chart Test](http://bl.ocks.org/godds/ec089a2cf3e06a2cd5fc)
The problem I am having when I un-zoom. I can't get the bars back to the viewable area. I am thinking the issue is in the brushed function. But can't figure it out.

```
function brushed() {
    // update the main chart's x axis data range
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? xOverview.domain() : brush.extent());
    // redraw the bars on the main chart
    layer.selectAll(".bar")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + ",0)"; })
    // redraw the x axis of the main chart
    layer.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

I have a complete example on js fiddle: [js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/eloew/1acpo7zv/16/)

How can I get the bars back to the viewable area after zooming?  Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be working with double-clck...

Comment: It does unzoom some on double click, but no unzooming all the way.There is spacing beteen bars and the rest run outsize the chart.